# JPA Entities with different schemas in test and production

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, database-schema

I have two JPA entities referring to two tables on my DB2 database, say :

- table FIRST on schema FIRSTSCHEMA
- table SECOND on schema SECONDSCHEMA

Both are accessible with the same credentials and datasources. Moreover, the schemas are different between test and production environments, then I have to load them from a configuration properties file.

My application uses Spring MVC and Hibernate. Entities are like the following :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FIRST")
public class FirstClass implements Serializable {
 ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="SECOND")
public class SecondClass implements Serializable {
 ....
}
```

With this "mode", the queries do all the work by configuring two Entity Managers Factory on the context.xml, one with default schema FIRSTSCHEMA and the second with default schema SECONDSCHEMA.

I would like to have a different way to query the database, also for transactional purposes (I execute not only SELECT queries).

Then I've seen that I could specify the schema as attribute of the @Table annotation. But this must be a constant expression (compile-time known) and I have to load it from the configuration properties, depending on the environment. Does anyone know a way to reach this goal, considering maybe a way of injecting values with Spring or any other techniques?

Comment: Hardcoding schema info in annotations is a bad idea, when you need to change deployment. You have `orm.xml`, or you have `persistence.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In maven, you can define profiles and you can set properties with that profiles.

If I were you I would define two profiles: `production` and `test`.

For example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      <properties>
        <schema.name>production_schema_name</schema.name>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
        <schema.name>test_schema_name</schema.name>
      </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then access the profile property with `${schema.name}`.

Hope help this.

Comment: Good idea but I don't think this can help me because I have to do an ear package for the customer and configure environment variables through external configuration files.

Comment: at that case you can store external configuration file paths as profile property?